# MS SQL Server Instances - How many instances do I really have?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have installed SQL Server 2016 Express and SQL Server Management Studio on my home computer. During installation I used option to create a named instance and nothing else. After that I have this:

[image: Connection screen]

Second line describes the named instance `SPOKANE` that I created, but what is the purpose of the first line? Which line should I use in which case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method I know for checking what SQL Server instances are installed is to use the SQL Server Configuration Manager - it displays all the services including the DBMS, Agent, SSAS servers etc.

I, for instance, have SQL Server Express, a full SQL Server, and SSAS:

[image: SQL Server Configuration Manager example showing instances]

SQL Server Express often gets installed as part of other software, or sometimes as part of a developer image provided by ITS when they first set up your computer - if you have an extra instance, it could have come about through any number of reasons. In your case the version you installed will be what you want to use - the other may be a different version from what you're expecting (e.g. SQL Server 2014 rather than 2016)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely other line(s) in the drop down list are result of a separate unrelated installation(s). To verify this, open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to both servers (you need to ensure that they are both running first), you will see something like this:

[image: Screen shot]

Note the versions of the servers: 9.0 and 13.0. This clearly indicates that they are from different installations.